# Using 'OR' and 'AND' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is using

`( Condition A or Condition B and Condition C )`

the same as

`( Condition A and Condition C)
OR (Condition B and Condition C)`

Comment: Why don't you try it and get back to us?

Comment: Regardless of the answer, I always absolutely recommend putting in the parens when mixing AND and OR conditions in any language. Readability is extremely important.

Comment: I'm waiting for data to be migrated, and I was thinking of the query in my head.

Comment: Absolutely 0 research

Comment: Joe is correct that you should use parens when mixing operators. Try writing out some [**truth tables**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to see if `(A and C) or (B and C)` is equivalent to `(A or (B and C))`. What about `((A or B) and C)`?

Comment: Since when can you not speak your thoughts?

Comment: If you read the [help page on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it specifically states that you should try and solve your problem on your own before asking other people for help, which you don't appear to have done. That's why you're getting downvotes.

Comment: Good to know, thanks Michelle. I would've figured it out on my own, if the data was migrated, hence this question

Answer (score 3):

No. The first condition is:

```
(Condition A) OR (Condition B and Condition C)
```

And the second is:

```
(Condition A and Condition C) OR (Condition B and Condition C)
```

You can clearly see the difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

> the first suggests that `a` or `B and C` is a must match
>
> the second suggests that `a and c` OR `b and c` are a must match

**(A) or (B and C)     `*IS NOT*`     (A and C) or (B and C)**

hope this makes more sence..

Comment: I don't really understand why you say that the first condition is `(A or B) and (C)`. `And` has the higher precedence, so the first condition, as written, is `A or (B and C)`

Comment: Aside from the point that this gets precedence wrong, it's incorrect. Draw up a truth table for `(A or B) and C` and for `(A and C) or (B and C)` and you'll see that they're logically equivalent.

Comment: `A or (b and c)` would maybe be equivilent to `a and c`  **AND** `b and a` but not `a and c` **or** `b and c` ...

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle Michelle was talking about the first revision of your answer, where you said that `(A or B) and C` wasn't the same as `(A and C) or (B and C)` when in fact, they are

Comment: Lamak is correct that I was commenting on your previous revision. Your current answer is correct, but you don't seem to actually understand or be able to explain _why_. (For the record, `A or (B and C)` is not at all equivalent to `(A and C) and (B and A)`.)

Answer (score 1):

The root issue here is that you should be including parens when mixing operators. Because `and` takes precedence, as written, you're asking whether

```
(A or (B and C))
```

is equivalent to

```
((A and C) or (B and C))
```

...and the answer is no. In the case where `A, B, and C` are `true, false, and false` respectively, the first condition evaluates to `true` whereas the second evaluates to `false`.

In order to make them equivalent, you could add parentheses to the first expression like this:

```
((A or B) and C)
```

In which case, for every combination of values for `A, B, and C`, it will evaluate to the same value as `((A and C) or (B and C))`.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to actually **explain** why they aren't equivalent, I was far too lazy in my answer